# Select latest 'N' records on the right table for each record on left table of left join on linq to sql

Tags: linq, left-join, ef-core-2.0

I want to select latest 2 records from the right table of left join for each pers_Id on left table in linq.

There is a lot of information to select top 1 or latest 1 but I want latest 'n' records from the Table2 below based on order date.

```
   Table1

pers_ID
10
20
null
40
meeting


    Table2

   pers_ID     STATUS            DATE
   10       initiated       10-APR-19
   10      processing       11-APR-19
   10      done             12-APR-19
   40      waiting          11-APR-19
   40      partial      12-APR-19
   40     interrupted       10-APR-19
   20      killed         11-APR-19


   result

pers_ID STATUS     date   
10  done        12-APR-19
10  processing  11-APR-19
40  partial     12-APR-19
40  waiting     11-APR-19
20  killed      11-APR-19
```

I am missing the important part here.

```
  from t1 in table1
  join t2 in table2 on t1.pers_Id equals 
  t2.pers_Id into tb
  from t2 in tb.DefaultIfEmpty()
  // Logic to fetch the latest 2 records from table2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should achieve the desire result.

```
 var n = 5;

 var query =  from t1 in table1
 join t2 in table2 on t1.pers_Id equals 
 t2.pers_Id into tb
 from t2 in tb.OrderByDescending(x=>x.ORD_CREATETIME).Take(n).DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new {t1,t2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to craft your query taking the first N items, rather than the last N items if possible. In this case, it certainly is possible by sorting in reverse order instead. Just add the sort clause (`orderby`) and take the first N items. Since your dates doesn't seem precise, you might want to sort by additional columns.

```
var n = 5;
var query =
    (from t1 in table1
    join t2 in table2 on t1.pers_Id equals t2.pers_Id into t2s
    from t2 in t2s.DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby t2.date descending, t2.pers_Id descending, t2.status descending
    select new { t1, t2 }).Take(n);
```

Comment: dont you think this will throw object reference exception on record for pers_id 'meeting' as there is no corresponding record to orderby?

Comment: @390278 , I have an edit in place. I would like to get 'n' latest records from table 2 for each of the pers_id from table 1 . The given solution will return a total of  'records' .

Answer (score 0):

I think for this scenario you have to use a GroupBy, but the query is going to be super slow:

```
var n = 2;
var query = (from t1 in table1 join t2 in table2 on t1.pers_Id equals t2.pers_Id select new {PersId = t1.pers_ID, Status = t2.Status, Date = t2.Date})
    .GroupBy(g => g.PersId)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date)
        .Select(s => new {PersId = x.Key, Status = x.Status, Date = x.Date})
        .Take(n))
    .SelectMany(sm => sm);
```